# Apply regex to all items of a QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

1. I use a ***QStandardItemModel*** with a ***QTtableview*** to hold regexes
2. I also use a ***QStandardItemModel** with a ***QTableview*** to which I want to apply all regexes from QTableview described in 1)

What is the best way to do that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to browse your model and apply a regular expression, you can use QAbstractItemModel::rowCount() and QAbstractItemModel::columnCount() and two loops to get each item in your model with QAbstractItemModel::item():

```
for ( int col = 0; col < model.columnCount(); ++col ) 
{
  for( int row = 0; row < model.rowCount(); ++row ) 
  {
    item = model.item( row, col );
    doSomething( item->text() );        
  }
}
```

If you want to filter your model to display only the items that match your regexp, you should use a QSortFilterModel.

Edit for small syntaxic typo and indent.